# LIKE statement but skips current post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use the LIKE condition to find similar posts.

Here is my code:

```
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    @post_gsub = Post.find(params[:id]).name.gsub(/something|something else|something else again/, '')

    @related_posts = Post.where("name LIKE '%#{@post_gsub}%'")
```

But when I pull this into the Rails view, there is currently always one match that shows up, which is the current blog post the user is on. How do I skip that current blog post so that "@related_posts" is only showing unique recommendations and not the post the user is currently on?

Comment: I'm not sure if intentional, but the regex `/something|something else|something else again/` will only hit `something`. It moves from left to right and stops when a match is found, so when `something` is hit it will use that match instead of looking further. `'something else'.gsub(/something|something else/, '') #=> " else"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can try chaining the `where.not` method</strike> Considering you're using Rails 3, you can use part of raw SQL:

```
Post.where('name LIKE ? AND id != ?', "%#{@post_gsub}%", @post.id)
```

That'll make your query to add a `!=` operator to get every post other than the one with id equal to @post.id.

Comment: shouldn't this be `where.not(id: @post.id)` ?

Comment: Do you mean I should explicitly use `@post.id`?

Comment: Actually, this didn't work what came back was ```wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)``` — I'm on Rails 3 if that matters.

Comment: Ooops. There's no `where.not` for Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

For rails 3 try

```
Post.where('name LIKE ? AND id != ?', "%#{@post_gsub}%", @post.id)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Will accept this answer when it lets me!